# How to add manual slide functionality in CSS slider

Tags: html, css, carousel

I would like to know how to add how to set on click functions to a "back" and "next" button that I will create in the CSS slider I have below. I can't figure a way to do this properly so any help is appreciated.

This is the plain slider that switches between images:

```
@keyframes slide {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
}

div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  animation: 30s slide infinite; 
}

<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img class="carousel" src="CustomerPro2.png" alt=""></div>
         alt="">
        <img class="carousel" src="CustomerPro22.png" alt=""></div>
         alt="">
        <img class="carousel" src="CustomerPro222.png" alt=""></div>
         alt="">
   </figure>
</div>
```

What I need help with is to set up two buttons that manually moves the images back and forth. Thank you.